# Workflow required to support vanity urls in iis and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

Can someone please walk me through the workflow required to support vanity URLs using IIS 7 and ASP.NET 4.0? What I want to do is be able to handle a request from the browser such as `http://john.mysite.com` and have it go to and execute my page at `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?id=3`. Of course the `id` would change depending on the url. `http://zack.mysite.com` might go to `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?id=4`.

What I am thinking is I need a database that holds the id's for `zack` and `john` and then I would implement a URL rewriter that would rewrite the url to the actual page (e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx?id=4`).

Can someone please tell me if I am on the right track here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I do believe this can be achieved using the [IIS URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) module.  Note that ASP.NET does [support some custom routing too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Brian -- do you have any links or resources showing any examples of this?

Comment: I think this is what you were trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698246/url-rewrite-issues-on-iis-7-0-with-subdomains-not-present-on-iis-7-5